# Converting time to 12 hour format in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I am using Cassandra 3.11.2. 
Cassandra is showing date and time in 24 hour format.How do i change this to  standard 12 hour format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The printing of time in `cqlsh` is controlled by `time_format` setting in the `[ui]` section of the `~/.cassandra/cqlshrc`.  The format string corresponds to the Python's `time.strftime` [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime). So you need to change to something like this (`%I` - 12 hours format, `%p` - AM/PM indicator):

```
[ui]
time_format = %Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p
```

Example:

```
cqlsh> create table test.tm(id int primary key, tm timestamp);
cqlsh> insert into test.tm(id,tm) values(1, '2018-06-18 18:30:55Z');
cqlsh> SELECT * from test.tm;

 id | tm
----+------------------------
  1 | 2018-06-18 08:30:55 PM    

(1 rows)
```

Comment: Hi Alex, it is not working for me. I have done the change in cqlshrc file and placed this inside .cassandra in home directory. to confirm this, I changed timezone which is reflecting but 12 hour format is not reflecting.

Comment: //This is my change//
datetimeformat = %Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p %z
timezone = Asia/Kolkata

Comment: I've added the example of my output... `datetimeformat` should be used by `COPY FROM/TO` command, not for output of `SELECT`

Comment: what version of the Cassandra? In older version there was an error in example of `cqlshrc` - they used `datettimeformat` instead of correct `time_format`: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14243

Comment: great man, it worked. I have added time_format instead of datetimeformat. I am using latest version Cassandra 3.11.2.